# Objeto Python Pickle en un modelo Django

Tags: python, django

quisiera saber cuál es la forma de incluir un objeto Python Pickle en un modelo Django. La BD está en postgressql. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer almacenándolo en una columna cadena de texto.

En `models.py`:

```
pickle = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

Serialización:

```
import pickle

todo = 'hello'
pickled_data = pickle.dumps(todo)
```

Deserialización:

```
import pickle

restored_data = pickle.loads(pickled_data)
```

Si en algún momento decides serializar un modelo, como te indica la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#pickling-objects), no se asegura retrocompatibilidad con otras versiones de Django.